# How to make lemmas about changes made to heap objects?

Tags: heap, dafny

I'm trying to implement a MaxHeap using Dafny based on the code from Intro. to Algorithms, CLRS 3rd edition, section 6.1, page 153 or the Max-Heapify function [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap). I switched from using recursion to a while loop because that seemed a bit easier to handle in Dafny.

Trying to prove the heap property on an array after calling the heapify function. In particular I was hoping to be able to use the require statement on heapify to assert that triples which didn't change in the heap which were satisfying the heap property before an update, are satisfying the heap property after the update.

However, after making any changes to the array it seems like it forgets all about the require/invariant statement. Even if I show that the value are the same before and after the update it still no longer passes the assertion. I pulled out the update into the swap method.

I was hoping I could write a lemma asserting this fact but it seems like lemmas don't allow modifying the heap or using old() or calling a method. Is there a way to write a lemma for this?

```
function method parent(i: int): int 
{
    i/2
}

function method left(i: int): int
{
    2*i
}

function method right(i: int): int
{
    2*i+1
}


class MaxHeap {
    var data: array<int>
    ghost var repr: set<object>

    constructor(data: array<int>) 
        ensures this.data == data
        ensures this in repr
    {
        this.data := data;
        this.repr := {this};
    }
    
    predicate method MaxHeapChildren(i: int)
        reads this, this.data
        requires 1 <= i
    {
        (left(i) > this.data.Length || this.data[i-1] >= this.data[left(i)-1]) && (right(i) > this.data.Length || this.data[i-1] >= this.data[right(i)-1])
    }

    method heapify(i: int) returns (largest: int)
        modifies this.data
        requires 1 <= i <= this.data.Length
        requires forall x :: i < x <= this.data.Length ==> MaxHeapChildren(x)
        // ensures multiset(this.data[..]) == multiset(old(this.data[..]))
        ensures forall x :: i <= x <= this.data.Length  ==> MaxHeapChildren(x)
        decreases this.data.Length - i
    {
        var i' := i;
        ghost var oldi := i;
        largest := i;
        var l := left(i);
        var r := right(i);
        ghost var count := 0;
        ghost var count' := 1;
        while !MaxHeapChildren(i')
            invariant count' == count + 1;
            invariant 1 <= largest <= this.data.Length
            invariant l == left(i')
            invariant r == right(i')
            invariant 1 <= i' <= this.data.Length
            invariant i' == i || i' == left(oldi) || i' == right(oldi)
            invariant largest == i'
            invariant count == 0 ==> oldi == i
            invariant oldi > 0
            invariant count > 0 ==> oldi == parent(i')
            invariant count > 0 ==> MaxHeapChildren(oldi)
            invariant count > 0 ==> forall x :: i <= x < i' ==> old(this.data)[x] == this.data[x]
            invariant count > 0 ==> forall x :: i <= x < i' && left(x+1) < this.data.Length ==> old(this.data)[left(x+1)] == this.data[left(x+1)]
            invariant count > 0 ==> forall x :: i <= x < i' && right(x+1) < this.data.Length ==> old(this.data)[right(x+1)] == this.data[right(x+1)]
            // invariant count > 0 ==> forall x :: i <= x <= i' && left(x+1) ==> MaxHeapChildren(left(x+1))
            invariant forall x :: i <= x <= this.data.Length && x != i' ==> MaxHeapChildren(x)
            decreases this.data.Length-i';
        {
            if l <= this.data.Length && this.data[l-1] > this.data[i'-1] {
                largest := l;
            }

            if r <= this.data.Length && this.data[r-1] > this.data[largest-1] {
                largest := r;
            }
            if largest != i' {
                assert forall x :: i <  x <= this.data.Length && x != i' ==> MaxHeapChildren(x);
                swap(this, i', largest);
                label AfterChange:
                oldi := i';
                assert MaxHeapChildren(oldi);
                i' := largest;
                assert forall x :: largest <  x <= this.data.Length && x != i' ==> MaxHeapChildren(x);
                l := left(i');
                r := right(i');
                
                assert forall x :: i <= x < i' ==> old@AfterChange(this.data[x]) == this.data[x] && left(x+1) < this.data.Length ==> old(this.data)[left(x+1)] == this.data[left(x+1)] && right(x+1) < this.data.Length ==> old(this.data)[right(x+1)] == this.data[right(x+1)];
            }else{
                assert MaxHeapChildren(i');
                assert MaxHeapChildren(oldi);
            }
            count := count + 1;
            count' := count' + 1;
        }
    }
}

method swap(heap: MaxHeap, i: int, largest: int) 
    modifies heap.data
    requires 1 <= i < largest <= heap.data.Length
    requires heap.data[largest-1] > heap.data[i-1]
    requires left(i) <= heap.data.Length ==> heap.data[largest-1] >= heap.data[left(i)-1]
    requires right(i) <= heap.data.Length ==> heap.data[largest-1] >= heap.data[right(i)-1]
    requires forall x :: i <= x <= heap.data.Length && x != i ==> heap.MaxHeapChildren(x)
    ensures heap.data[i-1] == old(heap.data[largest-1])
    ensures heap.data[largest-1] == old(heap.data[i-1])
    ensures heap.MaxHeapChildren(i)
    ensures forall x :: 1 <= x <= heap.data.Length && x != i && x != largest ==> heap.data[x-1] == old(heap.data[x-1]) 
    ensures forall x :: i <= x <= heap.data.Length && x != largest ==> heap.MaxHeapChildren(x)
{
    ghost var oldData := heap.data[..];
    var temp := heap.data[i-1];
    heap.data[i-1] := heap.data[largest-1];
    heap.data[largest-1] := temp;
    var z:int :| assume i < z <= heap.data.Length && z != largest;
    var lz: int := left(z);
    var rz: int := right(z);
    assert heap.data[z-1] == old(heap.data[z-1]);
    assert lz != i && lz != largest && lz <= heap.data.Length ==> heap.data[lz-1] == old(heap.data[lz-1]);
    assert rz != i && rz != largest && rz <= heap.data.Length ==> heap.data[rz-1] == old(heap.data[rz-1]);
    assert heap.MaxHeapChildren(z);

}
```

```
/**
        heapify(4)
        length = 17
        i = 4
        left = 8, 7 (0based)
        right = 9, 8 (0based)
        x in 5 .. 17 :: MaxHeapChildren(x) (i+1)..17 

         0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 
        [20,18,16,3,14,12,10, 8, 6, 4, 2, 0, 1,-2, 4, 4,-5]


        i = 8
        left = 16
        right = 17
        x in i' .. i-1 :: MaxHeapChildren (4..15)
         0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 
        [20,18,16,8,14,12,10, 3, 6, 4, 2, 0, 1,-2, 4, 4,-5]


        i = 16
        left = 32
        right = 33
        x in i' .. i-1 :: MaxHeapChildren (4..16) + 17.. MaxHeapChildren
         0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 
        [20,18,16,8,14,12,10, 4, 6, 4, 2, 0, 1,-2, 4, 3,-5]
     */
```

Comment: I haven't looked closely what is wrong with your encoding and where verification is failing. But I am able to verify it - https://gist.githubusercontent.com/rdivyanshu/80608b305c18b19cea6108a823ede06e/raw/699259917f9fb20eccc852da80ab1effdcf85b43/maxHeap.dfy

Comment: Thank you Divyanshu, I will study your code! It seems like, because I did not formulate the correct invariant for the algorithm to begin with, I reached the situation that I did. So in one sense my question is invalid, because writing a lemma about the heap was not needed, but I'm still curious if is possible to write lemmas about heap objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, I think what you are looking for is called a [`twostate lemma`](https://dafny.org/dafny/DafnyRef/DafnyRef#sec-two-state)
Basically, you can use `old()` in their specification, and at the call site, you can specify which heap to consider for calls to `old()` by suffixing the lemma's name by `@a`, if  `label a:` existed before that method's call.